# Store Local And Global Variable in linux?

Tags: linux

Where are the local variables and global variables stored in linux ? What is the difference between kernel stack and code stack in linux ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much every modern Linux distro uses address space layout randomisation today, so it is hard to tell where the stack or the heap or the data sections will land.

But in general, globals would go into the data or bss segment, depending on whether they're initialized, and local variables would go into the stack.

As for kernel stack, it's a 8kb fixed size stack that you cannot use directly. It's used within system calls and interrupts. Best forget about it, because it's not really of any use to you.